# how can I set a value in a setter in c#

Tags: c#

I want to add custom logic where my ulong will get set to 1 if it is 0 (default). Here's what I have:

```
    private ulong quantity;

    public ulong Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.quantity;
        }

        set 
        {
            if (this.Quantity == 0)
            {
                this.quantity = 1;
                return;
            }

            this.Quantity = this.quantity;
        }
    }
```

However, I'm getting a compile error that says:

`Parameter 'value' of 'PurchaseForPayoutRequest.Quantity.set(ulong)' is never used`

Comment: You need to reference `value`, not `this.Quantity` in your setter

Comment: `value` is the placeholder for the value assigned to the property (e.g. `Quantity = 5L` will lead to `value` being 5).

Comment: `this.quantity = value;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are using [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) correctly, you need to use `value` and make sure you are accessing your backing field. Your example can also be simplified with [expression body members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) and a [`?:` Operator](http://?:%20Operator%20(C#%20Reference))

```
private ulong _quantity;

public ulong Quantity
{
   get => _quantity;
   set => _quantity = value == 0 ? (ulong)1 : value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to be using the [contextual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value) `value` in your setter.

```
public ulong Quantity
{
    get
    {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    set 
    {
        if (value == 0)
        {
            this.quantity = 1;
            return;
        }

        this.quantity = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value to this.quantity in your last line

```
public ulong quantity
{
    get
    {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    set 
    {
        if (value == 0)
        {
            this.quantity = 1;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.quantity = value;
        }
    }
}
```

in else substitute value with number you want to get assigned when quantity is not 0.